# How to identify missing collections by Python?

Tags: python, blend-files, linked-data

I found a solution to the library link through [other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210766/how-to-get-the-missing-library-and-its-collection-with-python/210819#210819), but I haven't found a solution to the collection link yet, so I wrote this more specifically in this question.

If the name of the collection in the library changes, the blend file on the side you are referring to shows that the link is broken. When opening the file, the info editor informs you of the missing collection and you can also check the torn paper icon in the outline.

I want to identify these missing collections using Python. Is there an API related to missing collectoin?

[image: blender info editor]

[image: blender outliner editor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Read from the original**

For example sake have library "xxxx.blend", in it I have renamed a collection from "OLD" to "NEW", the previously linked collection "OLD" is in my blend but broken.

All the collection names in the library.

```
>>> lib = D.libraries['xxxx.blend']
>>> with D.libraries.load(lib.filepath) as (data_from, data_to):
...     data_from.collections[:]
...     
['NEW']
```

All collection names in my blend linked from lib

```
>>> [c.name for c in D.collections if c.library is lib]
['OLD']
```

If it's the same collection, renaming and reloading does the trick.

```
>>> D.collections['OLD'].name = 'NEW'
>>> lib.reload()
```

.. or get rid of it

```
>>> D.collections.remove(D.collections['OLD'])
```

*Careful note re above that linked collections can have the same name as an existing collection. So to use keying and be sure it is the one desired, add the filepath of the library*

```
>>> D.collections.keys()
['NEW', 'NEW']

>>> D.collections['NEW', lib.filepath]
bpy.data.collections['NEW']

>>> D.collections['NEW', lib.filepath].library is lib
True
```

**Use sets**

For a more robust solution recommend using sets. Using example above compare the names in library

```
set(data_from.collections)
```

against

```
set(c.name for c in D.collections if c.library is lib)
```