# Collection Loading Script Error

Tags: python

I'm new to scripting in Blender. Keep getting no error with this script I've fumbled with for the past two weeks. Wanted to know how to modify it based off Blender.

```
import bpy
import os
import glob

def collectionLoader(path, file_list):
    master_collection=bpy.context.scene.collection
    corpus=[]
    
    for path in file_list:
        with open(path, 'r') as file_input:
            corpus.append(file_input.read())
            
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(file_list) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections=data_from.collections
                        
        for new_coll in data_to.collections:
            instance=bpy.data.objects.new(new_coll.name, None)
            instance.instance_type='COLLECTION'
            instance.instance_collection=new_coll
            master_collection.objects.link(instance)
    
path="E:\Mack's Blender Work\Buildings\Houses\BlenderHouses"
file_list=glob.glob("*.blend")
collectionLoader(path, file_list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pathlib version.**

- When using a python `with` statement it is often the case that any variables defined within are no longer valid. Within the library load import statement `data_from`  and `data_to` are a list of strings [Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210882/how-to-identify-missing-collections-by-python). And then outside as a list of objects. [See Docs for more.](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLibraries.load)
- If new to python recommend using [pathlib](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f)  and simply use forward slashes as a folder delimiter.
- As an example have modularised the methods. One to load collections from all blends in a folder, returning a dictionary keyed by blend file name, and with the collections list as values.  The other to make and return collection instances from a list of collections.
- Then to test looped over the result, and linked each newly created empty to the context collection objects collection.
- Tested.

Test script

```
import bpy


def create_instances(collections):
    empties = {}
    for col in collections:
        mt = bpy.data.objects.new(
                f"{col.name}",
                None,
                )

        mt.instance_type = 'COLLECTION'
        mt.instance_collection = col
        empties[mt.name] = mt
    return empties

def load_collections(filepath):
    from pathlib import Path
    root = Path(filepath)
    collections = {}
    for fp in root.glob('**/*.blend'):
        with bpy.data.libraries.load(str(fp)) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections = data_from.collections
        collections[fp.name] = data_to.collections
    return collections


# test call.

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
collection = context.collection or scene.collection

# use forward slashes
for blend, collections in load_collections("/home/batfinger/Desktop").items():
    print(f"{blend} : {len(collections)}")
    for name, mt in create_instances(collections).items():
        print(f"\t{mt.name}")
        collection.objects.link(mt)
```

Sample output.  Test run, succesfully linked the following

```
test.blend : 5
    Group.040
    Group.041
    Group.042
    Group.043
    Group.044
untitled.blend : 1
    Collection 1.081
stinky.blend : 1
    Collection 1.082
mb.blend : 1
    Collection 1.083
collinktest.blend : 1
    Collection 1.084
fluzeug.blend : 2
    PERVANE.012
    Collection 1.085
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I'm really looking to evolve my coding. I've done data structures in other languages and I'm still relatively new to python. But learning how to manipulate Blender/Python has been a challenge. I've only been studying the Blender Python API book for like two weeks. I think I'll need to study some form of automation with python next though.

Comment: Pleasure.  Idea of seperation above is ultimately to create a class  `class CollectionLoader:` and edit  above methods eg `def load_collections(self):`  where filepath would be set in the init method _eg_  `def __init__(self, filepath, recurse=True, instance=True): self.filepath = filepath`

Answer (score 0):

```
import bpy
import glob
from pathlib import Path

def collectionLoader(path):
    master_collection=bpy.context.scene.collection
    
    for i in path:
        with open(bpy.data.libraries.load(path)) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to_collections=data_from.collections
            
        for new_coll in data_to.collections:
            instance=bpy.data.objects.new(new_coll.name, None)
            instance.instance_type='COLLECTION'
            instance.instance_collection=new_coll
            master_collection.objects.link(instance)
            
path="E:\Mack's Blender Work\Buildings\Houses\BlenderHouses"

collectionLoader(path)
```

Comment: Getting no error from this. But still no collections loaded from any .blend files under path. Not understanding.